# Organizing search bar and buttons with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm putting together a little web app using React and Firebase and I'm having trouble lining things up.

Ideally, I'd like the search bar and buttons to end up being centered on the screen in a straight line — search bar, then green button, then yellow, then red. All touching one another. If the page size is shrunken, the buttons ideally would shrink and stay in line with the search bar.

HTML

```
<div class="searchArea">
<div class="formWrapper">
<input class="playerInput" placeholder="Search by player name" />
</div>
<div class="formButtons">
<button class="upvoteButton">&#9650;</button>
<button class="downvoteButton">&#9660;</button>
<button class="injuryButton">&times;</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the pen — https://codepen.io/scottmiller2/pen/bYNPVm

Any direction is appreciated. I tried a lot of margin tweaking but set it back to default and put it in a pen. I've made things like this work before with trial and error, but I'm curious of how things should properly be lined up like this when preparing for resizing of a window. Thanks in advance

Here is the code which displays the search section:

```
<div className="playersFooter">
<PlayerForm addPlayer={this.addPlayer}/>
</div>
```

Corresponding CSS

```
.playersFooter {
display: flex;
flex: 1 1 5%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox more-or-less saved web devs from the position/float/negative-margin mess few years ago. It's easy even without the wrappers:

```css
.searchArea {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.playerInput {
  width: 450px;
  min-width: 300px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 55px;
  border: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(34, 49, 63, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.playerInput:focus {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: #111;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.upvoteButton {
  background-color: #00ab9e;
}

.downvoteButton {
  background-color: #fcce66;
}

.injuryButton {
  background-color: #fb655a;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.upvoteButton:hover {
  background-color: #02ffb6;
}

.downvoteButton:hover {
  background-color: #fbf03e;
}

.injuryButton:hover {
  background-color: #fd483a;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchArea">
  <input class="playerInput" placeholder="Search by player name" />
  <button class="upvoteButton">&#9650;</button>
  <button class="downvoteButton">&#9660;</button>
  <button class="injuryButton">&times;</button>
</div>
```

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/helb/pen/eemwGp

Comment: This lined things up very well.. especially in code pen. However, when I throw it in visual studio with my react code, it keeps the search box pinned to the left side of the screen, and underneath the section it should be just above. I see the search content is in a class called playersFooter, which has some flex CSS. I edited my initial post and included the css it has in it. If I remove the playersFooter class (or change it), the search bar centers to the screen exactly how we wanted, but doesn't display any of the other site content.

Comment: I added your align and justify center to the playersFooter and it put it up right near where it needs to be. I think that will do! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, i was asleep. :) In the snippet, i added `min-height: 100vh` to `.searchArea `, so it takes up entire viewport height, pushing other elements out of it.

Comment: …i added a simple footer (stuck to the bottom edge of viewport) to that codepen: https://codepen.io/helb/pen/eemwGp

Answer (score 1):

FlexBox is useful for centering elements vertically and horizontally in a div -> buttons centered on a navbar. I believe this is what you're asking. The code pen you linked seems unrelated to your description. The pen seems to just use a `position: absolute;`

[Intro to Flexbox Link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use table-layout for this :

```css
/* updates/addition */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.searchArea {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

.formWrapper,
.formButtons {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.formButtons {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}

.formButtons button {
  font-size: 1rem;
  /* to hide swallow white-space and instead float:right initially used*/
}


/* end addition */


/*search box*/

.playerInput {
  width: 450px;
  min-width: 300px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 55px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(34, 49, 63, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.playerInput:focus {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);
  color: #111;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

.upvoteButton {
  border: none;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #00ab9e;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.downvoteButton {
  border: none;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #fcce66;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.injuryButton {
  border: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #fb655a;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.upvoteButton:hover {
  background-color: #02ffb6;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.downvoteButton:hover {
  background-color: #fbf03e;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.injuryButton:hover {
  background-color: #fd483a;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchArea">
  <div class="formWrapper">
    <input class="playerInput" placeholder="Search by player name" />
  </div>
  <div class="formButtons">
    <button class="upvoteButton">&#9650;</button>
    <button class="downvoteButton">&#9660;</button>
    <button class="injuryButton">&times;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No man, you don't need flexbox for this. It's really simple, but it depends on approach (which can make it unnecessary complicated).

If your search area is ALWAYS going to be in the top left corner, you can use position: absolute and definitely REMOVE margin: auto. That by itself puts buttons on the same line as search box. when you resize, the buttons will go behind that search box (positioning removes the element from the normal flow so basically the buttons now don't even know the search box is there). You can fix this by setting the minimum width of the .searchArea or even of the body. I've found 670-680px to do the trick.
I have removed 'margin-top' from button elements. It doesn't do any good.

```css
.searchArea {
  min-width: 675px;
}

.formWrapper {
  position: absolute; 
}

.formButtons {
  float:right;
}

/*search box*/
.playerInput{
    width: 450px;
    min-width: 300px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 55px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(34,49,63,0.8);
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.playerInput:focus{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);
    color: #111;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

.upvoteButton {
  border: none;
  /*removed individual floats */
  /*   I have removed the margin from here*/
  height: 55px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #00ab9e;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.downvoteButton {
  border: none;
  /*removed individual floats */
  /*   I have removed the margin from here*/
  height: 55px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #fcce66;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.injuryButton {
  border: none;
  /*removed individual floats */
  /*   I have removed the margin from here*/
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #fb655a;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.upvoteButton:hover {
  background-color: #02ffb6;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.downvoteButton:hover {
  background-color: #fbf03e;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.injuryButton:hover {
  background-color: #fd483a;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchArea">
  <div class="formWrapper">
    <input class="playerInput" placeholder="Search by player name" />
  </div>
  <div class="formButtons">
    <button class="upvoteButton">&#9650;</button>
    <button class="downvoteButton">&#9660;</button>
    <button class="injuryButton">&times;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code is still FAR from perfect and I could tweak it more, but I wanted to give you an easy and quick fix so you know where to start.

If you want me to tweak it even further, please do let me know.

And if this solution works for you, consider accepting and upvoting this answer.

Comment: You don't "need" flexbox for most things, but it makes life way easier. ;)